# Passing values to view with the adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I've implemented (thanks to a tutorial) a way to show a custom listView, with images, names and description.

I used the `simpleAdapter` to pass the strings `name` and `description` to the textViews, and the int of an image's Id (the image is stored in R.drawable) to the imageView.

The problem is: now i should set the ImageViews to display images downloaded from the web, so I have drawables but i can't get IDs from them.

How can i customize the simpleAdapter to pass a `Drawable` to the `imageView`, and set the image with the `setImageDrawable` method?

Please be clear! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the viewBinder, as show here:

```
        adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                            String textRepresentation) {

                    if(data instanceof BitmapDrawable ){
                            ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable((Drawable)data);
                            return true;
                    }else{
                            return false;
                    }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-load-image-from-url-example/

Or to load from External media files you have already downloaded:

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(“/sdcard/myImage.jpg”);

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToShow);

myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult... so I would advise to use [CommonsWare's ThumbnailAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail).